# How to use atoi conversion in C using gets_s - example code included

Tags: c

I'm teaching myself about structures in C, and am having trouble compiling this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Date {
    int Month;
    int Day;
    int Year;
};

void AddDecade(struct Date);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct Date BDay;
    char buffer[50];

    printf("What month were you born? ");
    BDay.Month = atoi(gets_s(buffer, 50));

    printf("What day were you born? ");
    BDay.Day = atoi(gets_s(buffer, 50));

    printf("What year were you born? ");
    BDay.year = atoi(gets_s(buffer, 50));

    printf("You were born on %d, %d, %d?\n", BDay.Month, BDay.Day, BDay.Year);

    AddDecade(BDay);

    printf("You will be 10 years older on %d, %d, %d\n", BDay.Month, BDay.Day, BDay.Year);
}

void AddDecade(struct Date Target) {
    Target.Year += 10;
}
```

The author of the code compiled it without error on a Windows machine, but on my Linux machine gcc gives the following errors:

> 07_04_structures2.c: In function ‘main’:
>
> 07_04_structures2.c:18:5: **warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’
>   makes pointer from integer without a cast** [enabled by default]
>
> /usr/include/stdlib.h:148:12: **note: expected ‘const char *’ but
>   argument is of type ‘int’**
>
> 07_04_structures2.c:21:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes
>   pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>
> /usr/include/stdlib.h:148:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but
>   argument is of type ‘int’
>
> 07_04_structures2.c:24:9: error: ‘struct Date’ has no member named
>   ‘year’
>
> 07_04_structures2.c:24:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes
>   pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>
> /usr/include/stdlib.h:148:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but
>   argument is of type ‘int’

Given this line:

```
BDay.Month = atoi(gets_s(buffer, 50));
```

My understanding is that gets_s copies a maximum of 50 bytes of input into buffer, and passes a pointer to the variable 'buffer', to atoi, but according to this error:

> note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’

perhaps gets_s is at fault here? I've never used it before...

I'd be very thankful for a detailed explanation of what's wrong, and how to fix it.

Thanks a lot!

---

**Update:**

I implemented all of your recommendations and have come up with the following working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Date {
    int Month; 
    int Day;
    int Year;
};

struct Date AddDecade(struct Date);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct Date BDay;
    char buffer[50];
    char *buffer_end;

    printf("What month were you born? ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    BDay.Month = strtol(buffer, &buffer_end, 10);

    printf("What day were you born? ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    BDay.Day = strtol(buffer, &buffer_end, 10);

    printf("What year were you born? ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    BDay.Year = strtol(buffer, &buffer_end, 10);

    printf("You were born on %d, %d, %d?\n", BDay.Month, BDay.Day, BDay.Year);

    BDay = AddDecade(BDay);

    printf("You will be 10 years older on %d, %d, %d\n", BDay.Month, BDay.Day, BDay.Year);
}

struct Date
AddDecade(struct Date Target) {
    Target.Year += 10;
    return Target;
}
```

This has been a great learning experience for me! Thank you! :)

Comment: On another note, `BDay.year = atoi(gets_s(buffer, 50));` causes the error third line from below, the field is capitalised, `Year`.

Comment: Well, since you are teaching yourself C, it might a good time to tell you that you should not be using `atoi`. Even though this function is not officially deprecated, it really has no meaningful practical uses, since it provides no feedback in case of an error. If you need to convert a string representation of a number into an actual value, use functions from `strto...` group. Forget about `ato...` functions for good. Any time you see it used in the actual code, it is a direct indication of bad code quality.

Comment: Regarding: `strtol`, `strtoll`, & `strtoq` - Reading the man pages fully illustrate what you mean about atoi being deprecated. The `strto...` functions are really useful because of their support for returning error feedback. From the manual pages:

"The strtol() function returns the result of the conversion, unless  the value  would  underflow  or overflow.  If an underflow occurs, strtol() returns LONG_MIN.  If an overflow occurs,  strtol() returns  LONG_MAX..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_s()` isn't implemented in the Linux C library, so the compiler assumes the default of it being a function that returns and `int` takes whatever (promoted) parameters you pass it.

You'll need to recode to avoid using `gets_s()`. Probably the simplest fix is to use `fgets()` instead.  Change the lines similar to:

```
BDay.Month = atoi(gets_s(buffer, 50));
```

with:

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
BDay.Month = atoi(buffer);
```

Comment: `fgets` also returns `buffer`, unless it fails, which you should of course check for.

Comment: Your suggested fix got the ball rolling for me which eventually helped me fix the issues, and learn a great deal. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`gets_s` is a function defined in C11 and it is defined as an optional extension.

You have to compile your program with C11 support otherwise the `gets_s` function is not declared in `stdio.h`. When the function is not declared in `stdio.h` and there is no available prototype for the function like in your program, `gcc` will then implicity provide a prototype for `gets_s` that returns an `int` (implicit function declaration).

On `gcc` compiling with C11 is done with option `-std=c11` on `gcc` 4.7 and `-std=c1x` in older `gcc`. Note that as of today support of C11 in `gcc` (and Linux C libraries like glibc or eglibc) is still very incomplete and `gets_s` may be also not declared even when C11 option is enabled (not to mention the extension is optional).

Comment: I'm using gcc version 4.6.2 20111027, and compilation still failed after using the `-std=c1x` switch. Thanks for letting me know all of the specifics about `gets_s`!

Comment: @Totoro See my last paragraph, `gets_s` is probably still not implemented with your version of `gcc` and the libc you are using. Remember that C11 has been released since only 1 month!

Answer (score 2):

`gets_s` is not standard function in most versions of C language.

Since you didn't declare `get_s`, the compiler assume (as default) that it returns `int`, and hence the error.

Also, look at the error at line 24. (you should change `year` to `Year`)

Comment: It's very helpful knowing what is standard practice, what is deprecated, and what is simply not in standard use in the world of C. Good resources of information when learning C are really appreciated!